# Display an EditField in a ListField of BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, listfield

In my app i have to display list of items with price in `EditField`. How can i add `EditField` in list?

For `ListField`, i am using this code

```java
public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index,
        int y, int width) {

    this.listField=listField;
    String text=(String) get(listField, index);
    if(holder[index]==null)
    {
        holder[index]=placeholder;
    }
    graphics.setColor(rgb);
    graphics.setFont(Utility.getBigFont(DConfig.getFSize()+4));
    graphics.drawBitmap(3,y+7,placeholder.getWidth(), placeholder.getHeight(),holder[index], 0, 0);
    graphics.drawText(text,100,y+15);  
    graphics.drawText("Price:",100,y+30);
    graphics.drawText(CartScreen.price[index],100,y+45);
    graphics.drawLine(0, y+74, DConfig.disWidth, y+74);
}
```

How can i add edit field to list of rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to actually place the EditField in there. Your best bet is to use just a VerticalFieldManager and stack LabelFields/EditFields in there. It will still scroll, just won't be ListField.