# How to set width and height of TableView cells In BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have created a table in BlackBerry Java using [TableView](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/table/TableView.html) and [TableModel](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/table/TableModel.html).

Now, I want to set the width and height of particular cell.  How can I do that?

Comment: you want to add table in blackberry ?

Comment: yes i want to add table in blackberry

Comment: You can make a `VerticalFieldManager` looks like `UITableView`. For that you need to modify the `paint` and `sublayout` method. Modification of `paint` required for drawing row background for childs, and in `sublayout` you can control spacing between rows.

Comment: i have tried it even i made it using grid view, but i want to make a table using table view and table modal, i am getting problem using this.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options.  It partly depends on what features your table needs to support, but also what OS version you are targeting (what *minimum* OS version your app needs to run on).

Here are a few choices (I'm sure there are more, too):

1. if you can accept supporting only devices with OS 6.0 or above, then you could use the `TableModel`, and its associated classes from the RIM libraries.  [See this page for an example of that](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Table_Model_1328111_11.jsp).  This is a fairly well-architected approach to separating model from presentation.  There are also other classes, [RichList](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Rich_list_1228594_11.jsp) and [SimpleList](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Simple_list_1228593_11.jsp) that were introduced in OS 6.0.
2. if you need to support older OS versions, you could [use the ListField class](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800345/How_to_-_Make_list_items_appear_on_a_screen_.html?nodeid=800616&vernum=0), or the subclass called [ObjectListField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ObjectListField.html).  `ObjectListField` is especially easy to get setup to display a simple list (table).  But, you may find it limiting, and need to resort to a third major option ...
3. you can always make your own list/table, by extending the `Manager` class, or using `VerticalFieldManager`.  Each row in the vertical list would be a `Field` that you can define however you like.  [Here's a recent stack overflow question I answered showing some code that basically does this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483128/custom-list-field-click-event/11536884#11536884).  If you're coming from Android or iOS, you might find this to be a little more work than you'd like, but it will give you complete control, and can support any OS version.

This is a bit of an open-ended question, so you may need to provide some more specifics about how the table will look, or what kind of interactions each row will support - for example,

1. is each row selectable?
2. does each row have multiple fields within it, and are they each clickable/selectable?
3. does every row fit a consistent format, or do some rows have unique layouts?

Then, we might be able to give more specific recommendations.

P.S.  There used to be a great link that BlackBerry maintained (like what Google has for Android) concerning the market share of current devices.  It died, and [this is the best replacement I've found (update: link now also obsolete!)](https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/appworld).  It looks like probably 80% of paid smartphone apps are downloaded by phones running OS 6.0 or above.  It's hard to tell exactly, as that link is showing data as of May 31, 2012.  But, that at least gives you an idea, if you don't know which minimum OS to target.

Comment: i want to add a table with border and fixing widths of cell

Comment: all cells are of same size, so just to read the cells text i want a scroll in cells means if text is more then the cell size so it may not be visible all but it can be readable through scroll

Comment: @Aman, do you have requirements for the minimum OS version your app must support?

Comment: No type of such requirement i have 5.0 version and 6.0 version with me so i can use it using table view and table modal in OS 6.0

Comment: I am trying but unable to get the result.