# List field in blackberry , event click listener not working

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I am working on BB OS v5.0. I have managed to get the list to appear on the screen. I am getting data from webservice and adding it into a `Vector`.

Now I want to find out onclick, which is the item that is clicked and accordingly perform some operation. For that i am trying to display an alert. But I'm not getting the alert.

Here is my code :

In my mainscreen , i added `fieldmanager=new VerticalFieldManager();` and `add(fieldmanager);`

```java
void fetchAlbumsForLetter(String letter) {
    Status.show("Processing ....", 3000);
    fieldManager.deleteAll();

    VerticalFieldManager top = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH){
        public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(0x00290008);
            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            graphics.clear();
            graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, sha.getWidth(),
            sha.getHeight(), sha, 0, 0);
            super.paint(graphics);
        }
    };
    add(top);

    CustomListField4 list4 = new CustomListField4(null){
        protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
            getValue4();
            return true;
        }
    };
    fieldmanager.add(list4);
}

protected void getValue4() {
    Field f = getFieldWithFocus();
    if (f instanceof ListField) {
        ListField l = (ListField) f;
        final int index = l.getSelectedIndex();
        HistoryItem _contactslist = (HistoryItem) CustomListField4.val4.elementAt(index);
        final String id = _contactslist.getName();
        Dialog.alert(id+"");
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this

**EDIT**

```java
class CustomListField4 extends ListField implements ListFieldCallback {

    public CustomListField4(Vector data) {
        super(0, ListField.MULTI_SELECT);
        final TableRowManager row = new TableRowManager() {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                // g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                g.setColor(0x0f3e19b);
                g.clear();
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };

        Bitmap icon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("Devil Skype.png");
        HorizontalFieldManager h=new HorizontalFieldManager();
        h.add(new BitmapField(icon));
        //h.add(new BitmapField(song.getThumb()));
        h.add(new LabelField(song.getAlbumName()));
        //h.add(new LabelField(row1.getLanguage()));
        //h.setMargin(0,0,50,0);
        //Dialog.alert(song.getName());

        VerticalFieldManager vfm=new VerticalFieldManager();
        vfm.add(h);
        //vfm.add(new LabelField(song.getArtist()));
        row.add(vfm);
        contacts.addElement(row);
    }

    setSize( contacts.size());
}

// ListFieldCallback Implementation
public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics g, int index, int y, int width) {
    listField.setRowHeight(index,107);
    CustomListField4 list = (CustomListField4) listField;
    TableRowManager rowManager = (TableRowManager) CustomListField4.contacts.elementAt(index);
    rowManager.drawRow(g, 0, y, width, list.getRowHeight());
}

public class TableRowManager extends Manager {
    public TableRowManager() {
        super(0);
    }
```

Comment: Please post some of the code from your `CustomListField4` class.  We don't know what that is.  I don't see anything above that's wrong, unless it's something in `CustomListField4`, or perhaps in the way you lookup `index` in your contacts list.

Comment: @Signare, I didn't understand your comment 100%.  You think `fetchAlbumsForLetter()` is being called as a result of a button click?

Comment: @user2291839, what does your `CustomListField4` inherit from?  What class does it `extend`?

Comment: @Nate class CustomListField4 extends ListField implements ListFieldCallback

Comment: @Nate you know any solutions ?

Comment: @Nate check the comment on your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling getFieldWithFocus() which will give you the manager. You need to get the leaf field

```
protected void getValue4() {
   Field f = getLeafFieldWithFocus();
   if (f instanceof ListField) {
       //Your code
   }
}
```

Comment: iam adding the list to the Vertical field manager inside a button click. So when i debug, iam getting Field f = getLeafFieldWithFocus();. But iam not getting f instanceof ListField. f not an instance of listfield. Thats the error iam getting.

Comment: @Signare I hope you understand the difference between `getFieldWithFocus()` and `getLeafFieldWithFocus()`. The first function will give you the field that is direct child of your screen that "contains" focus - in your case the vertical field manager. Using the second function will give you the field object that actually has the focus.

Comment: What is the type of field that you get? try doing a sysout on the field's class name - `f.getClass.getName()`

Comment: Also make sure you are accessing the `getLeafFieldWithFocus()` of the screen and not some other manager. This is possible if your `getValue4()` method is defined inside some manager. You can try doing `getScreen().getLeafFieldWithFocus()` if doing within a manager.

Comment: What do you mean by f.getClass().getName() is not valid?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29573/discussion-between-adwiv-and-meera)

Answer (score 0):

I think your hierarchy of `Field` and `Manager` objects is incorrect, and this is causing problems with your detection of field focus/selection.

It wasn't obvious from the original code you posted, but by looking at your update, I assume that you are calling `fetchAlbumsForLetter()` once *for every row*.  That's not right.

`fetchAlbumsForLetter()` is creating a new `CustomListField4` each time it's called.  And, `CustomListField4` is a `ListField`.

A `ListField` is not meant to represent only **one** row.  It's meant to represent **all the rows**.  You should only create one instance of `CustomListField4`.

I would do either one of two things:

### 1. Continue to Use a ListField

If you want `CustomListField4` to be a `ListField` (`extends ListField`), then in your implementation of

```java
public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics g, int index, int y, int width);
```

you should actually **draw** graphics objects, using all the `Graphics#draw` methods.  These are primitive graphics items, like filled areas, lines, text, or bitmaps.  You would [not be using Field objects inside each ListField row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11486480/119114), as you're trying to do with your `TableRowManager` class.

[See here for a sample ListField](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Simple-ListField-example/td-p/426809/page/2), or [here for a more sophisticated example](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=898)

### 2. Imitate ListField with a Manager

change your code to

```java
public class CustomListField4 extends VerticalFieldManager {
```

or

```java
public class CustomListField4 extends Manager {
```

Then, you can use a `TableRowManager` for each row, and add `LabelField` or `BitmapField` objects to it.

[See here for an example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11536884/119114)

---

If you fix these problems, then I think the way you are overriding `navigationClick()` will work fine for detecting the row click, and doing something with the selected row.

Comment: when i add the same listfield5 in my mainscreen directly, then no problem occures. The problem occures when i add the list into a field manager.

Comment: also  if (f instanceof ListField) is not true in this case, because i addding list to field manager.

Comment: @Signare, there is no `listfield5` in this question or answer, so I'm not sure what you're referring to.  My suggestion was to completely re-write this code, because it incorrectly uses field and manager objects.  If you try this, and still have problems, please post a new question with the new code you're using.

Comment: @Signare, also, you're right that if you change `CustomListField4` to **not** inherit from `ListField`, then the check `f instanceof ListField` will always be false.  However, I'm not sure why that check exists anyway.  I don't think you need `if (f instanceof` at all.  Unless `getValue4()` is called from another `navigationClick()` method, too, it will always be called because of a click on the `CustomListField4`, right?  So, I don't think they need that check.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
 UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Dialog.alert(id+"");
                }
            });
```

Comment: `getValue4()` is already being run on the UI thread, so I don't think this will fix the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah you are right. Because I used this method when I couldn't display the dialog