# Custom List with lazy loading

Tags: blackberry, lazy-loading, custom-lists

I have successfully implemented like this for lazy loading in custom list
[image]

and the code I used for this is here:[Custom List With Images in Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273633/custom-list-with-images-in-blackberry)
In the linked question, I position the y coordinate of heart icon and I resolved the problemm of linked Question.

```java
 if (logoThumbnailImage != null
     && logoThumbnailImage.length > index
     && logoThumbnailImage[index] != null) {

       EncodedImage img = logoThumbnailImage[index];
       graphics.drawImage(0, y + 10, Display.getWidth(),
                          Display.getHeight() - 100, img, 0, 0, 0);
       graphics.drawImage(300,
                          y+400,
                          heart.getWidth(), heart.getHeight(), heart,
                          0, 0, 0);
```

Now I want to handle click event for both; that is, for list row click and on heart click

For that I saw a post written by @Nate here [Custom List Field click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483128/custom-list-field-click-event). But in that code the images are not loading from server and they are static Images.  I want to implement @Nate's code with my code (That is lazy loading ).

If you have any Idea please suggest how can I do that. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you start with the code I posted [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11536884/119114), and use the code you show in [this question to download images from a list of URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19273633/119114), then you should be able to achieve lazy image loading with the following changes:

Create a [listener interface that gets notified when downloads complete](http://javatechig.com/blackberry/how-to-download-image-in-blackberry/):

```java
public interface DownloadListener {
   // invokes if download success
   public void downloadSuccess(Bitmap bitmap);

   // invokes if download failed
   public void errorOccured();
}
```

Then, the Manager subclass that represents one list row, `CustomListRow`, is modified to implement this interface, and update the `_thumb` image when the download completes:

```java
public class CustomListRow extends Manager implements DownloadListener, FieldChangeListener {

   public void downloadSuccess(final Bitmap img) {
      _data.setThumb(img);
      // make sure bitmap is updated on the UI / main thread
      UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            _thumb.setBitmap(img);
         }
      });
   }

   public void errorOccured() {
       // TODO: handle error
   }
```

Then, you'll need to add some code to create all your threads to download images in the background, and notify the `DownloadListeners` when the image downloads complete.  You can decide **where** to do this.  In my example, I will do this in my `ListScreen` class, where I instantiate the `ListRander` data objects and the `CustomListField`:

```java
     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItem; i++) {
        ListRander lr = new ListRander("Product Name " + i, icon);  // icon is placeholder for thumbnail image
        data.addElement(lr);
     }
     final CustomListField list = new CustomListField(data);
     add(list);
     list.setChangeListener(this);

     pool = new ThreadPool(3);  // 3 concurrent download threads

     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItem; i++) {
        final int row = i;

        // create a new runnable to download the next image, and resize it:
        pool.assign(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                 try {            
                    String text=object[row].getJSONArray("UrlArray").getString(0).toString();
                    EncodedImage encodedImg = JPEGEncodedImage.encode(connectServerForImage(text), quality);    //connectserverForImage load Images from server                     
                    EncodedImage logoThumbnail = sizeImage(encodedImg, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight()-100);
                    list.getRow(row).downloadSuccess(logoThumbnail.getBitmap());
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    list.getRow(row).errorOccured();
                 }
              }
           }
        });
     }
```

You could do this in the `ListScreen` constructor, or whenever you have your `object[]` array of URLs.

You'll need to add a new method to `CustomListField`:

```java
public CustomListRow getRow(int row) {
    return (CustomListRow)getField(row);
}
```

The code above also needs a member variable added (in `ListScreen`) to create a thread pool:

```java
private ThreadPool pool;
```

This thread pool implementation is based on [this tutorial here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30483&seqNum=6), with very minor modifications, simply to change `ArrayList` (not available on BlackBerry Java) to `Vector` ... and removing the calls to `Thread#destroy()`.  You'll need to copy that tutorial's `ThreadPool`, `WorkerThread`, and `Done` classes to your project.  The above example I show creates a thread pool of 3 threads.  On a single CPU smartphone, 2 or 3 threads is probably fine for your needs.  [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4050341/119114) if you want to get the *perfect* number of threads for your application.

*Note: if possible, you can usually improve performance if you download images that are exactly the right size for your application, instead of burdening the network with larger images, and then resizing them inside your app.   However, I realize that this depends on having some control over the images' web server, which you may not have.  Just a thought for later optimization.*

Comment: Thanks @Nate for such a nice explanation of each point. I have successfully implemented the same.I have one more problem .I am unable to extend the size of image in customListRow .As I see there the sublayout method and tried to change the layoutChild(_thumb, thumbWidth, _thumb.getPreferredHeight()); and want to show the image   inlarge . I think you will understand what I am trying to point and if say I can post a new Question.

Comment: ,I resolve it also . Thanks. No need for new Question

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that I seen a good answer to this question on my travels, but can't find it now.  I do recommend reviewing the BB forums here:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/bd-p/java_dev
as there are similar questions there.

For now, just the highlights of what you need to do:

1. Create an image downloading runnable to process the download - you have pretty much already done this in your previous code.
2. Use the Observer pattern (search the internet for this), so that the BitmapField is the Observer for the completion of your image downloading. So when the image has been downloaded, the Runnable invokes the observer, which can then update the Bitmap.
3. Use a Thread pool with a limited number of Threads (I would say 3), so that you do not start a whole load of image downloads at the same time.  Search the internet for information on Thread Pool for help implementing this.  You had not done this step in your previous example, and you can get away with running all the downloads, but I expect at some stage that this will fail.

Put these together and you have your solution.  Not trivial I know.  Good luck.

Comment: As per your concern  the concept of observer pattern is the feasible solution of this problem .But I have problem in implementing the same.But Can you explain why I use the Thread Pool.Further If you have some code then please provide. I will highly appreciate it.

Comment: Don't have anything I can supply sorry.  I presume the Observer Pattern is no problem for you.  The Thread Pool is just a convenient way to limit the number of active Threads and so downloads, as there is no value attempting 50 downloads at once.  I suggest 3.