# showing data and images in list field from json Like Lazy loading Blackberry

Tags: java, json, blackberry, loading, lazy-evaluation

i have created a list filed which contains a Picture and some data in one row 
the picture and data i am getting from Json. My code is working but after getting the list my UI is hanging,
There are Two steps 
1) parse the data and image URL from json
2) and show in list field
I'll post my code and screen shot of List below

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/19759iD4089A71454F66E0/image-size/large/is-moderation-mode/true?v=mpbl-1&px=600

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen implements ListFieldCallback
{
    HttpConnection httpConn;
    int responseCode;
    private static ListField _list;
    private static Vector listElements = new Vector();
    private static Vector elements = new Vector();
    private static Vector contentelements = new Vector();
    private static Vector datelements = new Vector();
    private static Vector Imageselements = new Vector();

    LabelField label;
    String imagename;

    Bitmap bit ;

    Connection connectionthread;

    public MyScreen()
    {        
        // Set the displayed title of the screen  
        //setTitle("MyTitle");

        _list = new ListField();

        _list.invalidate();
        _list.setEmptyString("please wait..", DrawStyle.HCENTER);
        _list.setRowHeight(100);
        _list.setCallback(this);
        add(_list);

        connectionthread = new Connection();
        connectionthread.start();

    }

    public class Connection extends Thread{

        public void run() { 
            try {
                String httpURL = "http://192.168.1.91/bjp_app/program"+ getConnectionString();  

                httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(httpURL);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);

                responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode(); 
                if (responseCode != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) 
                { 
                    throw new IOException("HTTP response code: "+ responseCode); 
                    //System.out.println("\n Internaet problem HttpConnection. = "+responseCode);

                }else{
                    System.out.println("\n elseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee= ");
                    System.out.println("\nHttpConnection.HTTP_OK = "+responseCode);

                DataOutputStream _outStream = new DataOutputStream(httpConn.openDataOutputStream());

                byte[] request_body = httpURL.getBytes();
                for (int i = 0; i < request_body.length; i++) {

                    _outStream.writeByte(request_body[i]);
                }

                DataInputStream _inputStream = new DataInputStream(
                httpConn.openInputStream());

                StringBuffer _responseMessage = new StringBuffer();
                int ch;
                while ((ch = _inputStream.read()) != -1) {

                    _responseMessage.append((char) ch);
                }

                String res = (_responseMessage.toString());
                String responce = res.trim();
                System.out.println("\nresponce= "+responce);


                JSONArray jsnarry = new JSONArray(responce);

                System.out.println("\n--length----- "+jsnarry.length());

                for (int i = 0; i < jsnarry.length(); i++){

                    JSONArray inerarray = jsnarry.getJSONArray(i);
                    System.out.println("\n-innerarray-length----- "+inerarray.length());

                    //for (int i1 = 0; i1 < inerarray.length(); i1++) {
                        //System.out.println("\n-inerarray-values----- "+inerarray.getString(i1));
                        String ID = inerarray.getString(0);
                        String TITTLE = inerarray.getString(1);
                        String CONTENT = inerarray.getString(2);
                        String DATE = inerarray.getString(3);
                        String IMAGE = inerarray.getString(4);
                        String six = inerarray.getString(5);

                        System.out.println("................................................");
                        System.out.println("ID= "+ID);
                        System.out.println("TITTLE= "+TITTLE);
                        System.out.println("CONTENT= "+CONTENT);
                        System.out.println("DATE= "+DATE);
                        System.out.println("IMAGE= "+IMAGE);
                        imagename = "http://sanjaytandon.in/admin/image/"+IMAGE.trim();
                        System.out.println("imagename= "+imagename);
                        //System.out.println("six "+six);
                        System.out.println("....................................................=");
                       // String jsonresponse = ""+inerarray.getString(i1);
                        //label = new LabelField(jsonresponse,LabelField.FOCUSABLE);
                        //add(label);
                    //}
                        elements.addElement(TITTLE);
                        contentelements.addElement(CONTENT);
                        datelements.addElement(DATE);
                        Imageselements.addElement(imagename); 



                }


                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() { 

                    public void run() { 

                        try {
                            _list.setSize(elements.size());
                            _list.setSize(contentelements.size());
                            _list.setSize(datelements.size());
                            _list.setSize(Imageselements.size());
                            //invalidate();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            System.out.println("error _list.setSize"+e.toString());
                        }

                    } 

                });
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("\nresponce code error "+e.toString());
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Status.show("Check your internet connection!", 2000);
                    }
                });

            }

        }

    }

    public void drawListRow (ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index, int y, int w) {

        try {


            graphics.setGlobalAlpha(255);
            final int margin =5;

            String tittle = (String)elements.elementAt(index);
            String content = (String)contentelements.elementAt(index);
            String date = (String)datelements.elementAt(index);
            String imagesurl = (String)Imageselements.elementAt(index);

            UrlToImage img = new UrlToImage( imagesurl);

            bit =img.getbitmap();

            graphics.drawText(tittle.trim(), 3*margin+bit.getWidth(),  y+margin);

            graphics.drawText(content.trim(), 3*margin+bit.getWidth(), y+ margin+30);

            graphics.drawText(date.trim(), 3*margin+bit.getWidth(),    y+ margin+60);

            graphics.drawBitmap(2, y+margin+5, bit.getWidth(), bit.getHeight(), bit, 0, 0);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("error drawListRow"+e.toString());
        }

    }


    public Object get(ListField listField, int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix, int start) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
```

and MY UrlToImage.java class whcih downloads the images from URL

```
public class UrlToImage {

    public static Bitmap _bmap;

    UrlToImage(final String url){

        HttpConnection connection = null; 
        InputStream inputStream = null; 
        EncodedImage bitmap;
        byte[] dataArray = null;

        try { 

            connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url+ getConnectionString(), Connector.READ, true); 
            inputStream = connection.openInputStream(); 
            byte[] responseData = new byte[10000]; 

            int length = 0; 

            StringBuffer rawResponse = new StringBuffer(); 
            while (-1 != (length = inputStream.read(responseData))) 
            { 
                rawResponse.append(new String(responseData, 0, length)); 
            } 
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode(); 
            if (responseCode != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) 
            { 
                throw new IOException("HTTP response code: "+ responseCode); 
            }else{
                System.out.println("\nHttpConnection.HTTP_OK = "+responseCode);
            }

            final String result = rawResponse.toString(); 
            dataArray = result.getBytes(); 
            /*System.out.println("\ndataArray.length = "+dataArray.length);
            System.out.println("\ndataArray.length = "+dataArray[0]);
            System.out.println("\ndataArray.length = "+dataArray[1]);
            System.out.println("\ndataArray.length = "+dataArray[2]);
            System.out.println("\ndataArray.length = "+dataArray[3]);*/

        } catch (final Exception ex) { 

        }finally { 

            try { 

                inputStream.close(); 
                inputStream = null; 
                connection.close(); 
                connection = null; 
            } 
            catch(Exception e){

            } 
        } 

        bitmap = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(dataArray, 0,dataArray.length);
        // this will scale your image acc. to your height and width of bitmapfield

        int multH;
        int multW;
        int currHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        int currWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        multH= Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(currHeight),Fixed32.toFP(80));//height
        multW = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(currWidth),Fixed32.toFP(80));//width
        bitmap = bitmap.scaleImage32(multW,multH);

        _bmap=bitmap.getBitmap();

    }

    public String getConnectionString() {

      String connectionString = null;

      // Simulator behaviour is controlled by the USE_MDS_IN_SIMULATOR
      // variable.
      if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator()) {

          connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
          System.out.println("11111111111111111");
      }

      // Wifi is the preferred transmission method
      else if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) {

          connectionString = ";interface=wifi";
          System.out.println("222222222222222222");
      }

      // Is the carrier network the only way to connect?
      else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) 
      {

          String carrierUid = getCarrierBIBSUid();

          if (carrierUid == null) {
              // Has carrier coverage, but not BIBS. So use the carrier's TCP
              // network
             System.out.println("33333333333333333");
              connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
          } else {
              // otherwise, use the Uid to construct a valid carrier BIBS
              // request
             System.out.println("444444444444444444");
              connectionString = ";deviceside=false;connectionUID="+carrierUid + ";ConnectionType=mds-public";
          }
      }

      // Check for an MDS connection instead (BlackBerry Enterprise Server)
      else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) 
      {
         System.out.println("55555555555555555555");
          connectionString = ";deviceside=false";
      }

      // If there is no connection available abort to avoid hassling the user
      // unnecssarily.
      else if (CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_NONE) 
      {
         System.out.println("66666666666666666666");
          connectionString = "none";

      }

      // In theory, all bases are covered by now so this shouldn't be reachable.But hey, just in case ...
      else {
         System.out.println("77777777777777777777777");
          connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
      }

      return connectionString;
  }

  /**//**
   * Looks through the phone's service book for a carrier provided BIBS
   * network
   * 
   * @return The uid used to connect to that network.
   *//*
*/  private synchronized String getCarrierBIBSUid() {
      ServiceRecord[] records = ServiceBook.getSB().getRecords();
      int currentRecord;

      for (currentRecord = 0; currentRecord < records.length; currentRecord++) {
          if (records[currentRecord].getCid().toLowerCase().equals("ippp")) {
              if (records[currentRecord].getName().toLowerCase()
                      .indexOf("bibs") >= 0) {
                  return records[currentRecord].getUid();
              }
          }
      }

      return null;
  }
public Bitmap getbitmap()
{

    return _bmap;

}


}
```

Comment: I am getting list which contains data with images but my UI hangs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `ListField`, this method:

```java
public void drawListRow (ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index, int y, int w)
```

will be called on the main (*a.k.a.* "UI") thread.  This method is intended for **drawing**.  However, you have these lines of code in that method:

```java
       UrlToImage img = new UrlToImage( imagesurl);
       bit =img.getbitmap();
```

As you have implemented the `UrlToImage` class, that code is making a network call.  Network calls should not be made on the UI thread.  If you do so, your UI will hang/freeze.

What you should do is create a background worker (thread) that will go to the network to fetch your images.  You can decide whether you need to load **all** images immediately in the background, or only load images as the user scrolls the `ListField`.  When the images arrive (on the background thread), then you should tell the list field to redraw itself, row by row.

You might want to take a look [at this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19397269/119114), which performs lazy loading of imagery in the background.  That answer is a little different, in that it uses a custom list, not the standard `ListField`.  For a standard `ListField`, you can trigger a redraw of a list row with [ListField#invalidate(int)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListField.html#invalidate(int)):

```java
 // image for row 'x' download complete.  save image as member data
 //  that can be accessed in drawListRow().

 UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       _list.invalidate(x);
    }
 });
```

Comment: @user12345 - a Separate question I think.  Remember to do some research before you ask so that you can ask specific questions.